# Sqooping MS Access data into HDFS - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ms-access-2010, hdfs, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I have use case where I need to Import/Sqoop  Microsoft Access data into  hdfs. Is there any drivers available for MS Access to Sqoop data. Has any one came across such a case .
Please drop your comments and observations .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no support with access. [Here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1773570) is the list of supported databases from sqoop. The nearest is Microsoft SQL server [here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server). Main requirement is the jdbc driver to connect to database.